# How to properly pass down props to change a key in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I am trying to create a function that flips a value from false to true and vice versa in a JSON file. This is the JSON file, which has 4 of these:

```
[
  {
    "id": "0",
    "name": "Led Zeppelin",
    "isFavorite": false
  },
[...]
```

This is the component used to show each of the bands:

```
const Options = () => {
  const bandElements = bandList.map(band => (
    <Band
      key={band.id}
      id={band.id}
      isFavorite={band.isFavorite}
      name={band.name}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{bandElements}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Options;
```

And finally, the component in which I am trying to toggle that isFavorite property:

```
const Band = props => {
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
  const [allBands, setAllBands] = useState(bandList);

  function toggleFavorite(id) {
    const newArr = allBands.map(band => {
      if (band.id === id) {
        return { ...band, isFavorite: !band.isFavorite };
      }
      return band;
    });
    setAllBands(newArr);
  }

  const isSelected = props.isFavorite ? (
    <h3>OK</h3>
  ) : (
    hovered && <i className="icon-fix">&#128946;</i>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <li
        onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)}
        onClick={() => toggleFavorite(props.id)}
      >
        {props.name}
      </li>
      {isSelected}
    </>
  );
};

export default Band;
```

Comment: in `const [allBands, setAllBands] = useState(bandList)`, where is `bandList` coming from?

Comment: What I meant was that `bandList` is not defined within `Band` and the parameter within `useState` should be the initial value for that hook. If you need the bandList, you should pass it in as a prop and then use it for the initial value. I would say each Band probably doesn't need to know the state of all Bands, but that goes beyond the question.